# Why is operator $P = - i \frac{d}{dx} $ self-adjoint in this domain?

Tags: spectral-theory, differential-operators, self-adjoint-operators

The domain is (where $ac$ = absolutely continuous)

$$D(P) = \{f_{ac} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) | f' \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}$$

The text I am studying says that the functions that belong to $D(P)$ vanish at infinity. Why? Assuming that affirmation, the domain of the self-adjoint operator should be smaller than $D(P)$ because is only necessary that $g$ and $g'$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and so $P$ should not be self-adjoint. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that $g$ does not have to be ac?

Comment: Hint: although $g\in L^2(\mathbb R)\cap C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ does not imply that $g$ goes to $0$ at infinity, adding the condition on the derivative _implies_ that decay...

Comment: I haven't understood a think yet, why if $g,g' \in L^2(R)$ they should vanish at infinity? Doesn't imply only that g,g' are bounded at infinity?